# Retrieve data from Amazon s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I am trying to retrieve the URL of a picture from Amazon s3.

When I run the script below, I get an error:

```
Missing required Key in params
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


<script  src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.16.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

function test1(){

AWS.config.update({
accessKeyId: 'accesskey',
secretAccessKey: 'secretKey'
});


AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';


var myAWS = new AWS.S3();

myAWS.getObject(

{ Bucket: 'productissues', key: 'carlos.jpg' },

function (error, data) {
if (error != null) {
    alert("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
} else {
    alert("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes");
    // do something with data.body
}

});

}

</script>

</head>
 <body>

 <button type="button" onclick="test1();" >Click me!</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please go through this url for configuring your sdk first with proper parameters.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html

This part of your code is causing the error

```
AWS.config.update({
accessKeyId: 'accesskey',
secretAccessKey: 'secretKey'
});
```

You need to give your accessKeyId and secretAccessKey instead of defaulting them to accesskey and secretkey. They should be replaced with required values following the above url.

Also add 'Key' instead of 'key' in getObject params.

Comment: Hi Praveen, in my original code i am providing the right access. Do you see any issues with the rest of the code? thank you in advance!

Comment: Add 'Key' instead of 'key' in getObject params.

Comment: Praveen, i downloaded s3Fox organizer to see if the credentials are valid and they are not.I am trying to get a new secret key. I will let you know the outcome. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes, sorry it took so long. The person who created the account is in different country. The problem was the secret key. Now everything is working. One question. When I retrieve a file, I would like to get its URL, who can I do that? thank you in advance!