# Amazon S3 Data retrieval in URL for all the images in bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have my bucket on Amazon S3 filled with lot of images. I want to develop a API that would hotlink all the images to my website.
For this i want to write a code that would fetch the URL`s for all the images from bucket into a PHP - array.

I could`nt find code that would dynamically fetch the URL of all the files in bucket without passing the file name.

Waiting for help !!

Comment: Follow this link for Help !! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896259/retreive-data-from-amazon-s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to get the info is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html

Basically you create an iterator off of the bucket and then for each one you get the object URL.

```
$arr = array();
$iterator = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket
));

foreach ($iterator as $object) {
    $arr[] = $client->getObjectUrl($bucket, $object['Key']);
}
```